# Split the data using regex with google script

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

As a newbie, I have tried a lot to solve the below problem.

**My Current table**

```
    TestID            TestName                  Name       Url
    1592461  Google-page (www.google.com)
    1592467  Yahoo - Page (www.yahoo.com)
```

I am trying to split the data present in the column "TestName" and add the result to the columns "Name" and "URL" as given in the below table

**Expected table**

```
    TestID         TestName                      Name               Url
    1592461  Google-page (www.google.com)     Google-page    www.google.com
    1592467  Yahoo - Page (www.yahoo.com)     Yahoo - Page   www.yahoo.com
```

I have tried to compile the following script but was unsuccessful.

```
  function getUrl(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var s2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var data = s1.getSheetValues(1, 2, s1.getLastRow() , 1);
  var regExp = new RegExp("\(([^]]+)\)");

  var row = [];

  for(i = 0; i<data; i++) {

      var url = regExp.exec(data)[i];
      var output = s2.getRange("C2").setValue(url);

      logger.log(url);
      return url;
  }
}
```

Could someone please help me in solving this.

Comment: You have to provide more info. What error do you get? Use the Logger service to collect variables values at runtime and examine them to see what is being stored.

Comment: I don't get any data. The script runs and finishes blank

Answer (score 2):

In addition, I just wanted to let you know this can also be done with a (rather simple) formula. Enter in C1

```
=ArrayFormula(split(substitute(B2:B3, ")",""), "("))
```

Change range to suit.

Comment: Changing the formula slightly allows for the entire column, in cell C2 place: `=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B),,split(substitute(B2:B, ")",""), "(")))`  By providig no value for the TRUE part, the cell will still be blank. If I used "" an actual value is returned. This is important for other functions or scripts looking for empty rows. Changing the formula to the one below, it can be placed in cell C1 and will fill in the Headers. This keeps the formula out of the data row. =ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(A1:A)=1, {"Name", "URL"},IF(ISBLANK(B1:B),,split(substitute(B1:B, ")",""), "("))))

Comment: Thanks for the formula. But I wanted to achieve this using GAS. Much appreciate your help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

I have an impression you want to get the data from Column 2 of the current spreadsheet into Column 3 and 4 in the same spreadsheet.

I suggest using  the following regex:

```
var regExp = /(.*?)\(([^)]+)\)/;
```

The `(.*?)` will capture any 0+ chars other than line break chars into Group 1 (all before `(`) then `\(` will match a `(` and then `([^)]+)` will capture 1+ chars other than `)` into Group 2 (the URL) and then the `\)` will match a `)`.

And use it to analyze Column B data:

```
function getUrl(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var src_range = s1.getRange("B:B");  // Grab the Column B range
  var regExp = /(.*?)\(([^)]+)\)/;     // Define the regex
  for(i = 1; i<=src_range.getLastRow(); i++) { // Loop through all the cells in the range
    if (!src_range.getCell(i, 1).isBlank()) {  // If the cell is not blank, process it
      var m =  regExp.exec(src_range.getCell(i, 1).getValue()); // Run the regex
      if (m) {            // If there is a match
        var text = m[1];  // Text to be placed into Column C
        s1.getRange('C' + i).setValue(text);
        var url = m[2];   // URL to be placed into Column D
        s1.getRange('D' + i).setValue(url);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

See a [sample document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HbisRJWH-acrHs1qm-r3zLCt6RxXLf6Fx4CCKLTUyvE/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Thanks for the script @Wiktor, it works. But it's taking too much time to run as I have 220 rows of data.

Comment: Regex operations are known to take much time, if you can avoid regular expressions, avoid them.

Comment: Noted, Thank you very much.